# Centre of symmetry of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a $\triangle ABC$ wherein points $D,E,F$ are confined to move along the edges of $BC, AC, AB$ respectively such that $\triangle DEF \sim \triangle CAB$. What would be the centre of symmetry for the $\triangle FED$ ?

If instead $\triangle DEF \sim \triangle ABC$, then what would the centre of symmetry of$\triangle FED$ ?

By centre of symmetry, I mean the fixed point about which $\triangle ABC$ can be scaled and rotated to get the required $\triangle DEF$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a point is the orthocenter of $DEF$.

[image]

It is easier to build $ABC$ given $DEF$: since $\widehat{FAE}=\widehat{FDE}$ and so on, the circumcircles of $FAE,ECD,DBF$ meet on the orthocenter $H$ of $DEF$. Given that $D',E',F'$ are the mirror images of $D,E,F$ with respect to the midpoints of $EF,DF,DE$, we have:
$$\widehat{AFD'}=\widehat{AHD'}=\widehat{AED'}=\widehat{F'EC}=\widehat{F'HC}=\widehat{F'DC}=\widehat{BDE'}=\widehat{BHE'}=\widehat{BFE'},$$
so $H$ is the wanted symmetry point.

Comment: So what would be H in terms of $\triangle ABC$?

Comment: And what about the first case where $\triangle DEF \sim \triangle BAC$ ?

Comment: @user117913: if $DEF$ is not similar to $ABC$ as expected, but to $BCA,CAB,ACB$ or $CBA$, the the symmetry point is the mirror image of the orthocenter of $DEF$ with respect to an angle bisector of $DEF$. With respect to $ABC$ we have not a fixed point, but a point travelling on a curve (it should be an hyperbola).